# OpenShift Deployment

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

Hi I am new to open shift . I don't know how to create repository and deploying our project to it. I have configured it through command prompt. After installing rhc successfully through command prompt I am getting confusion of help given on Open Shift site regarding uploading the application not about pushing and commiting. I got the idea about commiting and pushing but I did not get the idea about deploying or uploading the application first time . Please help me I am getting stuck for a lot of time thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

**Deploying and Building Application**

All OpenShift applications are built around a Git source control workflow - you code locally, then push your changes to the server. The server then runs a number of hooks to build and configure your application, and finally restarts your application. Optionally, applications can elect to be built using Jenkins, or run using "hot deployment" which speeds up the deployment of code to OpenShift.

Making Changes to your Application
As a developer on OpenShift, you make code changes on your local machine, check those changes in locally, and then "push" those changes to OpenShift. One of the primary advantages of Git is that it does not require a continuous online presence in order to run. You can easily check in (in Git terminology, 'commit') and revert changes locally before deciding to upload those changes to OpenShift.

Every OpenShift application you create has its own Git repository that only you can access. If you create your application from the command line, rhc will automatically download a copy of that repository (Git calls this 'cloning') to your local system. If you create an application from the web console, you'll need to tell Git to clone the repository. Find the Git URL from the application page, and then run:

```
$ git clone <git_url> <directory to create>
```

Once you make changes, you'll need to 'add' and 'commit' those changes - 'add' tells Git that a file or set of files will become part of a larger check in, and 'commit' completes the check in. Git requires that each commit have a message to describe it.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "A checkin to my application"
```

Finally, you're ready to send your changes to your application - you'll 'push' these changes with:

```
$ git push
```

The output of the push command will contain information from OpenShift about your deployment -

Source [Click me](https://www.openshift.com/developers/deploying-and-building-applications)

Comment: I knows all this . I am facing problem for uploading my project first time .git add command will be of work later . It's not use ful for me . I am one step behind for this step

Comment: good description, thanks. I have here an app as-tjava.rhcloud.com. It worked initially after creation. It now shows 404. Icreated it in the webconsole (worked, no 404), then cloned, then removed src and pom with "git rm, git commit and push". Afterwards I again went to as-tjava and got 404. Why?

Answer (score 7):

There are two options for deploying content to the Tomcat Server within OpenShift. Both options
can be used together (i.e. build one archive from source and others pre-built)

1) (Preferred) You can upload your content in a Maven src structure as is this sample project and on 
git push have the application built and deployed.  For this to work you'll need your pom.xml at the 
root of your repository and a maven-war-plugin like in this sample to move the output from the build
to the webapps directory.  By default the warName is ROOT within pom.xml.  This will cause the 
webapp contents to be rendered at http://app_name-namespace.rhcloud.com/.  If you change the warName in 
pom.xml to app_name, your base url would then become http://app_name-namespace.rhcloud.com/app_name.

Note: If you are building locally you'll also want to add any output wars under webapps 
from the build to your .gitignore file.

Note: If you are running scaled EWS2.0 then you need an application deployed to the root context (i.e. 
http://app_name-namespace.rhcloud.com/) for the HAProxy load-balancer to recognize that the EWS2.0 instance 
is active.

or

2) You can git push pre-built wars into webapps/.  To do this
with the default repo you'll want to first run 'git rm -r src/ pom.xml' from the root of your repo.

Basic workflows for deploying pre-built content (each operation will require associated git add/commit/push operations to take effect):

A) Add new zipped content and deploy it:

1. cp target/example.war webapps/

B) Undeploy currently deployed content:

1. git rm webapps/example.war

C) Replace currently deployed zipped content with a new version and deploy it:

1. cp target/example.war webapps/

Note: You can get the information in the uri above from running 'rhc domain show'

If you have already committed large files to your git repo, you rewrite or reset the history of those files in git
to an earlier point in time and then 'git push --force' to apply those changes on the remote OpenShift server.  A 
git gc on the remote OpenShift repo can be forced with (Note: tidy also does other cleanup including clearing log
files and tmp dirs):

rhc app tidy -a appname

Whether you choose option 1) or 2) the end result will be the application 
deployed into the webapps directory. The webapps directory in the 
Tomcat distribution is the location end users can place 
their deployment content (e.g. war, ear, jar, sar files) to have it 
automatically deployed into the server runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Here is really good tutorial prepared by openshift guys with source code so you can go wrong with it.
https://www.openshift.com/blogs/spring-polyglot-persistence-part-1

To sum up - if you have your application on some repository just create your application so it creates folder with git repo in your directory

```
rhc app create notebook jbossas-7 -l <openshift_login_email> -d
```

Go to newly created directory and replace default openshift code with your repo

```
git rm -rf src/ pom.xml

git commit -am "removed default files"

git remote add notebook -m master git://github.com/shekhargulati/notebook-part1.git

git pull -s recursive -X theirs notebook master

git push
```

You should see your java application build.

Answer (score 0):

What application type is your app? Java/PHP/Python...? If it is a PHP based app, then externally exposed PHP code should go into "php" directory. Whenever you create an application using the rhc commands, a local repository is created, inside which you will find a README document, which lists your deployment steps. Additionally, you can refer to OpenShift user guide here:

https://www.openshift.com/sites/default/files/documents/OpenShift-2.0-User_Guide-en-US_5.pdf

Comment: My application is written in Java Technology.

Comment: Content was too long to post as a comment so I posted it as an answer!